# How many number of sequences (sample size) should be selected for randomness testing of bock cipher with 256 bits key and block length?

Tags: block-cipher, randomness, nist

I am working on randomness testing of block cipher. I have gone through the NIST two papers of randomness testing of AES candidate algorithm, links are given below

https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/publications/nistir/6390/final/documents/ir6390.pdf
https://tsapps.nist.gov/publication/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=151216
[image]
NIST used sample size for 128 bits block and key length which is attached in picture and for 256 bits key length and 128 bits block size NIST used 300 sequences (sample size).
now, I need how many number of sequences should be used for 256 bits block and key size?

Comment: Hiya and welcome! Err, AES only has a fixed block size of 128 bits. It's just the key that changes size.

Comment: Yes AES has block size 128 bits  but what if any other block cipher is used which has block size more than 128 bits